# FindDomNode deprecation warning in spite of using a ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component

```
const myMap = useRef(null);

 const [demo, setDemo] = useState({
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
  });

 const handleResize = () => {
    myMap.current &&
      setDemo({
        ...demo,
        height: myMap.current.clientHeight,
        width: myMap.current.clientWidth,
      });
  };

<Fragment>
       <ResizeDetector handleWidth handleHeight onResize={handleResize}>
          <div className="sm:w-3/5 sm:h-3/5 lg:w-4/5 lg:h-4/5" ref={myMap}>
            <ReactMapGL
              {...viewport}
              onViewportChange={(viewport) => setViewport(viewport)}
              mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
            ></ReactMapGL>
          </div>
       </ResizeDetector>
</Fragment>
```

I have used ref in my div but still, I get a deprecation warning that find dom node is deprecated, instead use a ref to the element you want to reference?

Is it a problem of react-resize-detector package or my fault?

Comment: I do not see any usage of `findDOMNode` in your code. Does the warning come from your code or third party code?

Comment: @Victor That's what I'm worried about, is the warning coming from third party package ie react-resize-detector because I did not use findDomNode, if so what should I do

Answer (score 0):

Your ref must be on a div wraping the `ResizeDetector`, and then pass a [new argument](https://github.com/maslianok/react-resize-detector/issues/68) (`targetRef`, 4.1.0) to `ResizeDetector`:

```
<div ref={parentRef}><ResizeDetector handleWidth onResize={() => onResize} targetRef={parentRef.current} /></div>
```